# Angular 5: RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs - what is the analogue in Angular 5

Tags: http, angular5, httpclient

I work on migration ng 4 to ng 5 and faced with

Just an example, I want to move to ng5 this method

```
getRequestOptions(): RequestOptionsArgs {
    const options = new RequestOptions();
    options.headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    });

    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    options.search = searchParams;

    return options;
}
```

The first question:
What is the analogue of RequestOptionsArgs in angular 5?

Comment: You can just use regular objects to represent the options to pass on a request. Have you seen the documentation for `HttpClient` in the Angular docs? They do a great job of explaining it. https://angular.io/guide/http#sending-data-to-the-server